# Observer in custom Ember view not always triggered on controller property change

Tags: ember.js

I want to filter an array of objects based on multiple criterias. Also sorting is possible. My setup so far: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/284/edit

Sorting and filtering works. But I am not reliably able to update my filter checkbox views, when a filter is toggled. The function `filterChanged` should be triggered whenever the `filterStop` array in the enclosing controller changes.

Some code excerpts:

```
App.FilterCheckbox = Ember.Checkbox.extend({
    'data-count': null
    isActive: false
    init: () ->
        # filterChanged only triggered if we set a breakpoint in the init function :/?
        this._super()
    filterChanged: (() ->
        active = this.get('controller.filterStop')[this.get('data-count')] == true
        this.set('isActive', active)
    ).observes('controller.filterStop.@each')
});
```

In my controller I have an action which changes `filterStop`:

```
filterByStops: (count) ->
    old_value = this.get('filterStop')[count]
    this.get('filterStop').replace(count, 1, [!old_value])
```

The strange thing now is, that the `filterChanged` observer function is not always triggered. If I set a breakpoint in the `FilterCheckbox.init` function and just continue execution after the breakpoint was hit, the observer always fires (as expected). If I remove the breakpoint and reload the page, the observer does not fire anymore.

Any ideas why this behavior depends on a breakpoint? How can I set this up, so that my checkbox can observe a property of its enclosing controller?

Update:
I just noticed that the debugger breakpoint trick only works in chrome with chrome dev tools. In Firefox (for OSX) with Firebug the trick/cheat did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Okey so I found out that I just need to explicitly tell the view what controller instance to use. The updated jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/287/edit

And my view code:

```
{{view App.FilterCheckbox data-count="2" controller=controller}}
```